# Is there story of supporting php and azure application insights in 2021?

Tags: php, azure-application-insights

I have really old PHP application that needs to be migrated to new version.

I am looking on analysing all calls HTTP && API from application or third party Software, without affecting the existing functionality and be able to know the stats

I thought of using Azure application insights as its already used for different part of business

**Constrains**

- I cannot install any modules to the server, I can only use PHP or files uploaded in current directory.

Is PHP supported?

I have found https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-PHP that is failing build and long out of any update (since 2019)

Answer (score 0):

It's sad to say that currently the Application Insights SDK for PHP is not maintained and supported by Microsoft. Even if you check this [Supported Platform for Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/platforms) document you won't find PHP in the supported language and SDKs.

The link which you are referring contains the SDK was supported by the Microsoft earlier, but now it's out dated without any maintenance. And Azure Monitor also provides support when using the supported SDKs. For now you can Follow [Azure Updates for Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/updates/?query=application%20insights) for the latest SDK news.

As a workaround you can try using [Open Telemetry for PHP](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/php/) which aid in the generation and collection of application telemetry data such as metrics, logs, and traces.